# Replace all numbers in a column with blank Except Particular Word

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code like if there is any number in the column need to replace with space or blank if there is any word contains in that column should not replace 
for Example:

```
A              A
1411000509   
1411000990   
1511000242   
1606000059    
1763104606    
1711001701    
1711001703
1763103223
1711001722
1763100137
ADDITION     ADDITION   
DELETION     DELETION
```

Comment: How do you decide whether to write "Blank" or put a space there?

Comment: I just need it blank if there is any number in that cell

Comment: Just use `IsNumeric` to test whether the value is a number and, if it is, use `Clear` to clear the cell (or set the `Value` to `""` if you prefer).  If you post your current code attempt, we can help you fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In B1 Cell**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),"",A1)
```

Drag the formula down.

**Using Coding**

```
Sub ClearNumericData()
Dim r As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each r In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    If IsNumeric(r.Value) Then r.ClearContents
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: in the same cell A only I need

Comment: Code Included in the original post to take care of your requirement.